# Editing a File "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, titanium, editing, safe-mode

I'm having trouble with my visual studio 2010. When I open a file and try to edit it, it crashes and gives the following message.

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working.

If I choose to debug, visual studio just-in-time debugger says:

> An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe [2812].
>
> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled Message: The calling
> thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The following was found in the event viewer:

> Application: devenv.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 6F29B036 (6F250000) with exit code 80131506.
>
> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
> Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.296, time stamp: 0x50484aa9
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset: 0x0004b036
> Faulting process id: 0xafc
> Faulting application start time: 0x01ce44dbc5e338e5
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio > 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
> Report Id: 09015696-b0cf-11e2-a33a-0023aee722ef

I have tried opening several different file types: xml, aspx, html, vb. They're all causing it to crash. I have run visual studio 2010 in safe mode and opened a single file, outside of a solution and it's crashing before I even edit the file.

It's only started doing this today. I have tried running the repair tool but it has made no difference. I have installed one thing on my machine that may have caused the error. Titanium Studio. Previous to that being installed visual studio 2010 was running okay.

Thanks

Leah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by requesting a hot fix from windows.

Knowledge Base Article: [FIX: "Faulting module name: clr.dll" error message when you run a Microsoft .NET Framework 4-based application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103)

Hot Fix Request: [DevDiv955340](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2640103&kbln=)

Comment: This hotfix is quite old and does not apply if you updated .NET to the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, imediately when Visual Studio 2010 was starting. Only rebooting helped sometimes.

I solved it by removing .NET completely and reinstalling it.

Be aware that if you updated to .NET 4.5 this includes .NET 4, so you have to remove and reinstall .NET 4.5